# Formik (Form) Wrapped with ScrollView Giving Warning Virtualized List React Native

Tags: react-native, formik, virtualization

Formik (Form) Wrapped inside ScrollView Giving Warning of Virtualized List can never be nested in React Native, but when i commented the Formik then BOOM! warning is gone.

I have tried to wrapped it inside the View & Block but didn't succeded. I have search for Formik property of ScrollView but it has non, What will the solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue just by removing the formik, actually it was the formik that was creating issue.